# null pointer exception in writing file in java

Tags: java, file-io, filewriter

I am facing an exception while writing to the file. i am giving the code below.

```
private static void readCsvFromFileAmazon(List<String> filelist) 
        throws BiffException, IOException,NullPointerException {

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("total_number_of_products_amazon.txt", true);
    String numberOfProducts = getProductNumber(url);

    System.out.println(category);
    System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + numberOfProducts);
    // call function to get the number of products. \
    if (!numberOfProducts.equals(null) || !numberOfProducts.equals(" "))
    {
        fw.write(numberOfProducts);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("cant write null product");
    }
    fw.close();
}
```

the value getting in number of products is null then exception happening

```
Exception in thread "main" 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@null
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

exception happening in this line

```
if(!numberOfProducts.equals(null)||!numberOfProducts.equals(" "))
```

Comment: Where on earth you compare a string with null using `equals()`

Comment: Does your `getProductNumber(url)` return something?

Comment: Well like mentioned in the error : 
numberOfProducts is returned as null here from getProductNumber()

Comment: i found this .equals checking in somewhere at the internet and tries..okk now i got the exception solved thank you

Answer (score 3):

You must check numberOfProducts content in different way:

`if(null != numberOfProducts ||!"".equals(numberOfProducts))`

instead of `if(!numberOfProducts.equals(null)||!numberOfProducts.equals(" "))`

because if `numberOfProducts` is `null`, then invoke a method `equals` on `null` object throws a `nullPointerException`.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

in your if statement `numberOfProducts.equals(null)`

you are comparing a string to a `null` string. this doesnt have any effect since you are comparing a null object.

remember that String is an object and you need to check object if they are `null` in this kind of way `numberOfProducts == null` or `numberOfProducts != null`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check if `null.equals(null)` - it throws an exception, NullPointerException, for tying to access the `equals()` method of `null`. First, make sure `numberOfProducts` is not `null` itself, using the `==` operator:

```
if (numberOfProducts == null) { 
   //do something
} else {
 ...
}
```

Also note that the line

```
if(!numberOfProducts.equals(null)||!numberOfProducts.equals(" "))
```

Makes no sense logically. Assuming `null.equals(null)` would work (IT DOES NOT), The second (right) operand - `!numberOfProducts.equals(" ")`, will be evaluated only if `numberOfProducts == null`, so whenever the right operand is evaluated - it will always yield `false`.

This means your condition could be shortened to simply:

```
if (numberOfProducts != null)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you posted for:

```
System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"+numberOfProducts);
```

Output is:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@null
```

This means `numberOfProducts` is `null` hence if you attempt to call any non-static method on it like this:

```
numberOfProducts.equals(null)
```

will throw a `NullPointerException`. If you want to check if it's `null`, do it like this

```
if (numberOfProducts != null && !numberOfProducts.equals(" ")) {
    fw.write(numberOfProducts);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work

```
if(numberOfProducts!=null && !numberOfProducts.rquals(" ")){
 //doSomething
}else{
 //doSomethingElse
}
```

Comment: It has a different logic (that could have been what the OP actually intended to have)

Comment: Yes, I too agree with that.